# Can't import Gerber file into Altium properly

Tags: altium, gerber, import

I am importing the top overlay Gerber file of the Arduino UNO board.  The Gerber file looks like this when opened in Altium:

[image]

When I imported it into my PCB drawing, it doesn't look the same as in the original file, especially the Arduino Logo, as can be seen below:

[image]

How can I import it properly?

[Here is my PCB document.](https://365.altium.com/files/07A2F5B9-A28C-44FB-ABFB-DAB5B69059ED)

[Here is the Gerber file for the top overlay.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aXKA3jD5ZpqcKHh81biAU0RotjLtpLWB/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: That's probably because Altium Designer interprets those files and the shapes differently under different conditions i.e. CAM viewer environment or PCB design environment. I don't think there's much you can do. Maybe you can import everything into the CAM document and export as PCBdoc if that's really what you want to do.

Comment: Why do you need to import it into Altium ? Is this to modify the Gerber file ? It is always better to import the original CAD files (even better if already in Altium format) and then modify and regenerate the Gerbers. A dedicated Gerber editor is better as Altium is limited on that front from what I know ...

Comment: Well I just need to like reverse engineering, that is to import the result back again into Altium and edit it.